# Pulling out a data based on 2 conditions of long data R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, visualization

I hope I word my questions clearly.

I am new with R, and I am currently working on a long data of text from 3 different corpora. My goal is to know the frequency (%) of a given string, occurring in a given corpus. This is the long data example:

```
Center     n   tag  
 1 apple   19  poetry
 2 melon   34  media
 3 lemon   1   spoken
 4 lemon   1   poetry
 5 peach   1   spoken
 6 apple   1   poetry
 7 orange  1   media
 8 banana  1   spoken
 9 banana  1   media
10 melon   1   media
...
```

Therefore, I would like to pull string "apple" and "melon", along with the frequency, based on the condition of tag. With this, I will be able to compare the frequency (%) of the strings in each different tags.

Example:

```
Center     %   tag  
 1 apple   4   poetry
 2 apple   34  media
 3 apple   23  spoken
 4 melon   15  poetry
 5 melon   23  spoken
 6 melon   2   poetry
```

Is there a function that lets me do this? My final goal is to visualize the dataframe using ggplot barplot.

I still have find ways to pull the data that way in long data. My current visualization is as follows:

[image]

It just shows a barplot of a frequency of each tags. What I want is in addition to the tags, it also shows the two variable of strings that I want to compare. And the measurment is not the frequency as in number, but rather frequency as in percentage relative to the tags.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your expected output? Do you want `transform(data, freq = n / sum(n) * 100)`, where `data` is your data frame? Do you want this, but seperated for each tag?

Comment: `library(dplyr); data |> mutate(share = n / sum(n), .by = tag)`

Comment: It's not only the expected output that is unclear, the problem and the aim are also unclear. Please try to make your case more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm simulating your data based on the "diamonds" data set. I agree with the comment that it's not quite clear what you want to achieve, but maybe the below helps:

```r
library(tidyverse)
## make similar data frame
df <- diamonds %>%
  select(Center = cut, n = table, tag = color)

## define your strings
strings <- c("Premium", "Good")

## filter those
df %>%
  filter(Center %in% strings) %>%
  ## calculate frequency of tag occurrence based on "n" within each Center
  ## this first step might not be necessary depending on how your data looks in real life
  group_by(Center, tag) %>%
  summarise(n = sum(n)) %>%
  ## this calculates the percentatge
  group_by(Center) %>%
  reframe(perc = round(100*n/sum(n)), tag = tag) %>%
  ## then pass this new data frame to ggplot
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(Center, perc, fill = tag))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'Center'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-12-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>